# Splitting column of strings into two columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a df with column "day" that contains strings that are in the format `"2020-12-31 19:00:00"`
I would like to split this string into two columns so that one column contains the date `"2020-12-31"` and the second column contains the time `19:00:00`. I tried

```
str_split_fixed(df$day, " ", 2)
```

But I got the error:

```
Error in df$day : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please show dput of small example.  The code you showed should work otherwise

Comment: I get the same error when I run your code since `df$day` is undefined (since `df` is a function in R, aka type `closure`). Are you sure you have the correct name of the data frame? After creating df using @Paul Smith's answer, your original code runs fine.

Comment: When I say it works, I assume that `df` is an object created with `day` as columns

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(day = "2020-12-31 19:00:00")

df %>% 
  separate(day, into = c("day", "time"), sep = " ")

#>          day     time
#> 1 2020-12-31 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# data
df <- tibble(x = "2020-12-31 19:00:00")

df %>% 
  mutate(x = str_split_fixed(x, " ", 2))
```

output:

```
  x[,1]      [,2]    
  <chr>      <chr>   
1 2020-12-31 19:00:00
```